# Why is the probability of choosing $2$ of $n$ elements if $n$ is large enough equal to probability multiplication?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits

I have a problem involving probability and limits. Suppose I have a garden with $x$ trees, of which $\frac19$ are red and the rest are green. I want to find the probability of choosing $2$ trees at random such that one is red and one is green.

I calculated this probability as

$$P=\frac{\binom{8x/9}{1}\binom{x/9}{1}}{\binom{x}{2}}$$

which depends on $x$. For example, when $x=9$, $P=\frac29$; when $x=90, P=\frac{160}{801}$.

I also proved that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}P=\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{9}\cdot\binom{2}{1}=\frac{16}{81}$$

However, I don’t understand why this limit makes sense intuitively. Why doesn’t the product of the individual probabilities of choosing a red tree and a green tree work with small $x$ while $\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{9}\cdot\binom{2}{1}$ is also the product of those probabilities?

Can someone please explain this to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a small number, the choices are dependent.  Knowing that your first trial was red gives you a lot of information about the second.  For gigantic samples, this dependence fades away.

Comment: I don't understand.  suppose you had a bag with two balls in it, one white one black.  Each draw is $50-50$, clearly.  If you take two at once, you obviously get one of each (that's the only possibility).  The colors are dependent.  If your bag had a billion of each the probability of each outcome would be at least statistically independent (i.e. there is some dependence, but it is very, very slight).

Comment: There is no advantage to "picking at the same time".  In my $2$ ball example, there is only one possible pair.  Say we had $4$ balls (two black, two white).  There is one all black pair, one all white pair, and four mixed pairs.  You are much more likely to draw a mixed pair.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine we pick the trees in order. The desired probability is $p=P( R_1,G_2   \cup G_1 R_2) = P( R_1,G_2)+  P(G_1, R_2)$ where $G_1,R_2$ denotes the event that the first tree is green and the second red. By symmetry, $p = 2 P(R_1,G_2)$.

But, using conditional probabilities $$P(R_1,G_2)=P(G_2 | R_1 ) P(R_1)$$

with $P(R_1)=\frac19$ and $P(G_2 | R_1 )=\frac{\frac89 x}{x-1}$. Hence

$$p=2 P(G_2 | R_1 ) P(R_1) = 2 \frac19 \frac89 \frac{x}{x-1}$$

Notice that $P(G_2|R_1)$ (probability of getting a green tree given that the first pick was a red tree) is, for large $x$, quite similar  to the unconditional probability of getting a green tree: $P(G_2 | R_1 )\approx P(G_2)=\frac89$ . This makes sense, because the fact that one red tree was removed from the garden turns insignificant is the number of trees is large.
Hence for large $x$

$$p \approx  2 P(G_2) P(R_1) = 2 \frac19 \frac89$$